# What's a reasonable size for a remote database for an Android application?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm in the process of designing the backend side of what intends to be an Android application for managing debts among friends (I know, there are already several applications that do this).

Similar to whatsapp, users of this application will form groups and will be able to create new expenses, where user A will owe user B a certain amount of money.

My initial idea was this:

1. The remote database will permanently hold data on users and groups.
2. However, it will hold data relative to debts only temporarily. When some user creates a new debt (for example, user A bought pizza for users B, C), he/she will upload it to the remote database. Then, when all users from that group have downloaded it, it will be deleted from the remote database.

This strategy requires implementing a 'coherence' mechanism that is not trivial, but not too complex either. The main point of this strategy would be minimizing the amount of data held by the remote database, which, in the hypothetical case it kept ALL debts and lots of users were using the application, would just explode in size.

Sadly, erasing old debts from the database as soon as all members of a group have them creates a number of problems. For example, if some user logs in from a different device, the remote database won't have all his data available.

The simple solution would be to just keep all data at all times in the remote database, but, before I take this path, I'd like to ask you:

1. Do you think keeping all data permanently on the server side is manageable in the long run and with a large number of users?
2. What are some common practices in similar contexts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the correct answer depends on accounting and regulatory requirements, not just whatever a bunch of programmers may think.

Comment: Well, I'm precisely interested in the opinion of programmers who have worked professionally on software that presented similar problems.